# typeface not applied no error thrown

Tags: android, fonts

Im trying to apply typeface to textviews and editTexts but the typeface silently fails with no error or exception in logs.There is no change in font and android default font is shown.

I have tried around 10 fonts nothing works(otf & ttf both) nothing worked

I also tried to convert it http://www.freefontconverter.com/ here as some answers suggested. But, still not working.

```
 typefaceLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MyriadProRegular.otf");
//        typefaceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HNBold.otf");
//                typefaceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica.ttf");
        typefaceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaBold.ttf");
        typefaceLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaLight.ttf");
        typefaceArialBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/helveticabold1.ttf");
//        typefaceLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HNLight.otf");
        registerTitleTv.setTypeface(typefaceBold);
        signInTittleTv.setTypeface(typefaceBold);
        termsSiginTextView.setTypeface(typefaceLight);
        termsSignUpTextview.setTypeface(typefaceLight)
```

[image]

I have referred to

[Custom Fonts not working in lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269264/custom-fonts-not-working-in-lollipop)

[Custom Font not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288182/custom-font-not-working-on-android)

[Changing the android typeface doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786553/changing-the-android-typeface-doesnt-work)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61771

[Android 5.0 (API 21) fails to render custom fonts / typefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584569/android-5-0-api-21-fails-to-render-custom-fonts-typefaces)

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried:

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "robotobold.ttf")

Comment: Tried still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems fine . I would suggest you either clean your code or uninstall app and install again .